# The English Longbamboo

Tags: weapons, climate, materials

Before we move on to this scenario, let us get the composite bow out of the way, as the scenario focuses on infantry, and composite bows, though more powerful than the routine English longbow, are made specifically for cavalry.

The longbow, famous in the medieval stories and images of knights waging battles on castles, is made of wood, usually yew.  In this alternate scenario, the longbow is made not from wood, but an import from the other side of the continent--bamboo.  [As I have said in a previous question,](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/65029/the-bamboo-skeleton) bamboo is exceptionally strong and can bend but never break.  No doubt that a bamboo longbow would be more lethal than a wooden one.

But the question is based on one of the flaws of the Mongol composite bow--**climate.**  In a humid climate, the animal glue used to put the composite together would lose cohesion and collapse the bow like a pile of bricks.

Europe is, for the most part, a pretty moist continent.  Would its humid climate pose a problem for the possibility of knights shooting knights with arrows released from bamboo longbows?

Comment: Knights shooting knights? If you are referring to Europe, I have hard time imagining that as knights used horses and lances to spear and trample (or try to, since they tended to fail if enemy pikemen had longer pikes) whatever stood in their way. If for any reason they fought on foot, they used swords instead. Knight-equivalents from other cultures might have had different attitude, but European ones considered bows demeaning, dishonourable, below them and worthy only of lowest classes.

Comment: Henry V's battle with the French at Agincourt used bows.

Comment: @Miech "Knights" fought on foot. They were then called "men at arms," making themselves heavy infantry. It's financially easier to take many peasants/freemen and train them to shoot crossbows/longbows than equip and train a knight, and thus the resentment of knights toward archers. (Don't forget there is a chance that the archer could possibly kill from a distance...) The archers will be happier with a salary and won't make any demands for land, too! Anyways, comments may not be the best place for this kind of myth-busting.

Comment: @JohnWDailey Except that less than quarter of Henry's forces were actual knights. It was French who fielded mostly knights (French army had more Knights than the size of entire English army), and Agincourt is famously knows as triumph of peasant archers over "noble" knights. You seem to think that everyone who fought in medieval times was a knight. You can't be further from truth than that. Knights were just one part of the force, with very specific class privileges. Apart from knights, armies consisted of paid servants, paid soldiers, drafted peasants and outright mercenaries.

Comment: @PipperChip Knight is a class of land owners, specialised in warfare. They are given land along with peasants (slaves) who inhabit it, and are supposed to train and equip themselves using revenue from the land and exploitation of serfs. Usually, they were also required to bring along a detachment of other soldiers and servant support. Exact details of how they fought depended on culture and period, but were pretty much limited to mounted/lance and foot/shield+sword. Archer killing a knight was a transgression (to knight) for reason you stated AND because lesser being dared to kill a noble.

Comment: There must have been a reason why the Japanese used [composite bows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yumi) "made by laminating bamboo, wood and leather".

Comment: A *Yumi* from the Samurai period was generally made of laminated wood.

Comment: I have to say this to stop the demons in my head, but bamboo IS wood.

Comment: @John  Bamboo is GRASS.

Comment: @JohnWDailey Do you think the two are mutually exclusive? It is composed of cellulose and lignin that makes it wood.

Comment: @John  Find the word "bamboo" in this link:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woody_plant

Comment: woody plant is a very different thing than wood, woody plants are defined by the presence of wood in specific places. It's like saying extinct bony sharks could not have had bone becasue sharks are not bony fish. Look up Monocot wood https://s10.lite.msu.edu/res/msu/botonl/b_online/e06/06h.htm#monocot

Comment: Congratulations to JohnWDailey for getting @Thucydides and slobodan the first Reversal badge on the site! Your track record of asking awful questions has paid off by being the first person to get an awful question a. not closed and b. onto 'hot network questions'. Also, shout out to Christmas weekend. What an accomplishment!

Comment: @kingledion  "Awful" is a subjective description, and therefore RUDE.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The traditional English Longbow was a form of composite bow, although it wasn't thought of that way by the makers and users. The bow was carved from a section of the trunk so that the bow's cross section had both the heartwood as well as the softer sap wood. The bowstave is cut from the radius of the tree so that sapwood (on the outside of the tree) becomes the back and forms about one third of the total thickness; the remaining two thirds or so is heartwood. Yew sapwood is good only in tension, while the heartwood is good in compression. This provided a means of both resisting the bending stresses and storing more of the mechanical energy the archer was using to draw the bow.

The ancient composite bow was far more efficient, since it was actually engineered to maximize energy storage and release using wood, horn and held together with glue (which did not fall apart with humidity or age. As Odysseus could tell you, a properly stored bow was still quite deadly when strung after 20 years).

The Japanese *yumi* used by the Samurai was generally made of laminated wood, making it also a form of composite bow. Your bamboo bow will be far *less* powerful than a *yumi*, proper composite bow or an English longbow, since the fibres essentially have uniform properties throughout. This isn't to say a bamboo bow would not be useful, but with the ability to store and release far less power than bows engineered out of proper materials, it might only be good for hunting small game, not driving a bodkin through armour plating.

Answer (score 22):

Your question relies on wrong premises:

**1st** Composite bows could be used both by infantry and by cavalry. Nomadic people such as Huns, Mongols, Manchu etc usually had 2 bows. The smaller one was used on horse and larger one while on foot, usually when facing foot archers.

**2nd** Humidity was not a problem. Compound bows was used since antiquity by cultures around the Mediterranean. Romans used it quite extensively see image below or search for Sagittarii

**3rd** Composite bow takes a skilled bowyer working many hours to produce one bow. On the other hand longbows could produced much more easily, similarly to modern serial production. Since the primary advantage of the composite bows is that its shorter, which doesn't matter very much when used by foot archers, the longbow was more cost effective weapons.

***Roman bow***
[image: Roman bow]
Image taken from [classic bow](http://www.classic-bow.com/store/traditional-roman-recurve-bow-g-241.html)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @JohnWDailey Your question premise is based on faulty assumption. Europeans didn't choose Yew because it was the best, but because it was cost effective. Even if bamboo has better properties if its expensive and/or difficult to work with it won't be adopted.

Comment: @slobodan.blazeski This. Good grief, THIS! Armies never cared and never will care what's best. They always cared and always will care about what's most cost effective. Any realistic "what if" army should always be considered from cost-effectiveness point of view, and nearly nothing else.

Comment: @Miech Absolutely as the old joke goes: "Always keep in mind that your weapon was made by the lowest bidder".

Answer (score 13):

## Not Any More Than Normal?

The longbows worked by using the fibers of whatever material like a spring. The English longbow worked well because there was a transition between the two types of wood which were naturally bonded together. One side worked very well in tension, and the other side in compression.

Absorbing water can be quite troublesome because it makes the wood swell. It puts some parts of the wood in compression which normally are not. Interfering with this compression and tension causes breaks or fractures, or at least introduce forces which conspire to weaken the bow. Bamboo, being a fiberous plant, will have the same issues with water absorbency.

The material [properties of bamboo](http://bambus.rwth-aachen.de/eng/reports/mechanical_properties/referat2.html) appears to be doing pretty well. This link shows discusses a little on how bamboo breaks; Yes, it will prefer to bend, and can bend quite a bit, but it does ultimately break. Being a grass, though, it could actually be more absorbent (I couldn't find any sources for the absorbency of bamboo vs. other materials.)

The same techniques for keeping wood dry would work for bamboo. Waxing, oiling, coating in fat, and wrapping in oily rags are good techniques that most cultures can employ.

Comment: Water damage is a potential risk, but we can suggest that it's not that significant as they [tested the bows from the Mary Rose](http://www.theinfinitecurve.com/archery/longbows-of-the-mary-rose/). If 400 years in salt water doesn't ruin them, getting a bit damp is probably fine.

Answer (score 13):

[Kyūdō](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ky%C5%ABd%C5%8D) - The art of Japanese archery with bamboo bows.
The yumi (Japanese bow) is exceptionally tall (standing over two metres), surpassing the height of the archer. Yumi are traditionally made of bamboo, wood and leather using techniques which have not changed for centuries,

So, yes, you can make an effective bow from bamboo. It would be best used by infantry, as the bow is quite large. And I believe that Japan is as moist as England as they are both islands. 
Note that bow strings getting wet and wearing out is a real problem for archers. Consider what happens when the bow works fine, but the string snaps at the wrong moment..

As to the question of knights shooting knights with bows, I believe that killing people effectively would decide that question. 
Plate armor was tested against pistol fire. Some existing breast plates have dents from bullets fired at them as part of proofing the armor, proving that it could stop a bullet. Can a long bow arrow penetrate plate armor? That decision may influence knight v. knight archery more than the size and material of a bow. 
By the way, have you heard of foot bows? Some bows were so hard to draw that they could only be fired by laying on your back, using both hands and pushing the bow with your feet.